# Why would you run a messaging queue (eg RabbitMQ) cluster?

Tags: rabbitmq, queue, distributed-system

> Overview
>
> A RabbitMQ broker is a logical grouping of one or several Erlang
>   nodes, each running the RabbitMQ application and sharing users,
>   virtual hosts, queues, exchanges, bindings, and runtime parameters.
>   Sometimes we refer to the collection of nodes as a cluster.

Why would you do this? I understand to increase durability of messages (if a node goes down, other queues still get the messages). But what about performance? How does cluster improve performance. Won't all consumers/producers connect to the master node's queue anyway? If so, aren't we still getting traffic on a single node regardless? Do we put a load balancer so traffic is directed at different nodes each time?

How does RabbitMQ cluster increase performance?

Comment: I don't know why this post was downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Well, right after that paragraph, the documentation states the following:

> **What is Replicated?**
>
> All data/state required for the operation of a RabbitMQ broker is
>   replicated across all nodes. An exception to this are message queues,
>   which by default reside on one node, though they are visible and
>   reachable from all nodes. To replicate queues across nodes in a
>   cluster, see the documentation on high availability (note that you
>   will need a working cluster first).

So, you would cluster to provide higher capacity in your RabbitMQ broker than a single node can provide alone. Note that [clustering by itself is not a high-availability strategy](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html).

Your assertion that message durability is increased is false, as message queues continue to reside on one broker (unless mirroring is used).

> By default, contents of a queue within a RabbitMQ cluster are located on a single node (the node on which the queue was declared) [[1]](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ha.html)

Without mirroring, when that node goes down, messages on it will be lost. The cluster will put the queue onto a different node. [RabbitMQ does not handle network partitions well](https://www.rabbitmq.com/partitions.html#suspend), so this can be a bit of a problem.

"Aren't we still getting traffic on a single node regardless?" - if you only have one queue, then yes. However, a bigger question is "why would you run a message broker with only one queue?" Similarly, if you only create queues on one node, then you will still have one point of failure in the system.

Comment: Ok, sorry I imlicitly meant that queues are mirrored. So in a cluster with mirrored queues (master queue on one node, mirror queues in other nodes), does it provide performance improvement or capacity improvement? I see neither.

Comment: Correct, it provides availability improvement, which is different.

Comment: In all reality, a properly-architected application should not rely upon the message queue for any sort of persistent storage; thus, there is little value in configuring mirroring.

Comment: So clustering with queue mirroring provides higher availability, but does not increase performance (ie throughput) ? What can one do to increase performance?

Comment: Correct. And the answer to increasing performance depends on what aspect of performance is in need of increasing.

Comment: Thanks. 1) i need to handle more messages coming from a single producer. 2) i have many producers residing on different servers. We can treat these as 2 separate cases.

Comment: My recommendation is to ask a separate question, providing relevant details for your case. It is probably the case that you have not exceeded the capacity of a single node, but are instead running into auto-throttling or some other issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166351/discussion-between-user1008636-and-themayer).